# Should I open and close db for each query?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am using old school ADO.net with C# so there is a lot of this kind of code. Is it better to make one function per query and open and close db each time, or run multiple queries with the same connection obect? Below is just one query for example purpose only.

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectMain"].ConnectionString))
    {
        // Add user to database, so they can't vote multiple times
        string sql = " insert into PollRespondents (PollId, MemberId) values (@PollId, @MemberId)";

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@PollId", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@PollId"].Value = PollId;

        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@MemberId", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@MemberId"].Value = Session["MemberId"];

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Int32 rowsAffected = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this for multiple consecutive queries (like 500 inserts)?  Or periodic queries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For most cases, opening and closing a connection per query is the way to go (as Chris Lively pointed out). However, There are some cases where you'll run into performance bottlenecks with this solution though.

For example, when dealing with very large volumes of relatively quick to execute queries that are dependent on previous results, I might suggest executing multiple queries in a single connection. You might encounter this when doing batch processing of data, or data massaging for reporting purposes.

Always be sure to use the 'using' wrapper to avoid mem leaks though, regardless of which pattern you follow.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the 'using' wrapper"?

Comment: @TrackABill.com  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            { //Something }

Answer (score 11):

Well, you could measure; but as long as you are `using` the connections (so they are disposed even if you get an exception), and have pooling enabled (for SQL server it is enabled by default) it won't matter hugely; closing (or disposing) just returns the *underlying* connection to the pool. Both approaches work. Sorry, that doesn't help much ;p

Just don't keep an open connection while you do other lengthy non-db  work. Close it and re-open it; you may actually get the same underlying connection back, but somebody else (another thread) might have made use of it while you weren't.

Answer (score 3):

If the methods are structured such that a single command is executed within a single method, then Yes: instantiate and dispose of the connection for each command.

If the methods are structured such that you have multiple commands executed in the same block of code, then the outer block needs to be the using clause for the connection.

ADO is very good about connection pooling so instantiating and disposing of the command object is going to be extremely fast and really won't impact performance.

As an example, we have a few pages that will execute update to 50 queries in order to compose the page.  Because there is branching code to determine the queries to run, we have each of them wrapped with their own `using (connection...)` clauses.

We once ripped those out and grabbed one connection object and passed it to the individual methods.  This had exactly zero performance improvement while complicating the hell out of the code with all the exception clauses every where to ensure the connection was properly disposed at the end.   At the end of the test, we rolled back the code to how it was before.  Much cleaner to know exactly what was going on and when a connection was being used.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as always, it depends.  If you have 5 database call to make within the same method call, you should probably use a single connection.

However, holding onto connection while nothing is happening isn't usually advised from a scalability standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

ADO.NET is old school now?  Wow, you just made me feel old.  To me Rogue Wave ODBC using Borland C++ on Windows 3.1 is old school.

To answer, in general you want to understand how your data drivers work.  Understand such concepts as connection pooling and learn to profile the transaction costs associate with connecting / disconnecting and executing queries.   Then take that knowledge and apply it it your situation.